# Точка или двоеточие после слова "пример"?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

*Пример: компания нашла поставщика для запуска новой линейки продукции. Теперь ей нужно договориться с ним о выгодной цене и удобных условиях поставки. И тут нередко возникает проблема: менеджеры зачастую не владеют навыками переговоров...*

*Пример. Компания нашла поставщика для запуска новой линейки продукции. Теперь ей нужно договориться с ним о выгодной цене и удобных условиях поставки. И тут нередко возникает проблема: менеджеры зачастую не владеют навыками переговоров...*

Часто замечаю вариант пунктуации с двоеточием, однако мне хочется поставить точку, т.к. "пример" относится ко всему последующему изложению. Верно ли это?

Розенталь: *Точка ставится в конце предложения, вводящего в дальнейшее развернутое изложение: Вот этот рассказ. (Пауст.) [дальше следует рассказ]; Представьте себе следующее, [дальше — подробное повествование]; Новый станок имеет такое устройство. [дальше — пространное описание]* (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=87#_ftnref10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поставить  двоеточие, если в качестве примера приводится одно предложение. Но если их несколько, то ставится точка. В Нацкорпусе используется сочетание "вот пример".

**Вот пример. Компания нашла поставщика для запуска новой линейки продукции, и теперь ей нужно договориться с ним о выгодной цене и удобных условиях поставки. Но тут нередко возникает проблема: менеджеры не всегда владеют навыками таких переговоров.**

Здесь примерно такая ситуация: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=87#pp87

9. Точка ставится **в конце предложения, вводящего в дальнейшее развернутое изложение:** Вот этот рассказ. (Пауст.) [дальше следует рассказ]; Представьте себе следующее, [дальше — подробное повествование]; Новый станок имеет такое устройство. [дальше — пространное описание].

Примеры:

(1) У нас заминки могут быть где угодно. **Вот пример.** Когда мы в Белоруссии работали, там таможенник мог остаться на работе, если его попросить, и до восьми вечера в пятницу. [Татьяна Гурова. Логика преодолевшего гибель // «Эксперт», 2014]

(2) **Вот пример:** в одном пакете молока только 5% ― его себестоимость; всё остальное ― упаковка, налоги и особенно высокие торговые надбавки, образующие доходность торгующих сетей.

**Пояснение к редактированию**

В этом тексте две основные мысли, поэтому скорее следует объединить два первых предложения, и уж конечно не делить на части третье. Вообще говоря, разбивка на короткие предложения связанных по смыслу фраз во многих случаях смотрится не лучшим образом.

Comment: Дельное замечание, но нет ответа на основной вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, ответ исправлен.

Comment: Кстати, хочу отметить, что указанным фрагментом пример не заканчивается.

Comment: Согласен, перед "теперь" стоит поставить запятую. Но с последним предложением всё ок. Точка с запятой слепит всё в одно огромное сложносочинённое предложение, а это не очень с точки зрения инфостиля.

Answer (score 2):

Согласен, что корректно ставить двоеточие, только если пример начинается и заканчивается в том же предложении. В Нацкорпусе нашлось 89 вхождений, где предложение состоит из одного слова *пример*.
Вот некоторые из них.

> Поэтому экономика знания оказывается довольно болезненным феноменом. **Пример**. Казалось, шансы нашего суперпроекта освоения Штокмановского газоконденсатного месторождения на арктическом шельфе безусловны. [Ольга Балла, Александр Пилясов. Экономика смыслов // «Знание-сила», 2013]
>
> Вот почему лучше брать довольно большие, но легкие камни. **Пример**. Чтобы камень радиусом 5 см и массой 100 г подпрыгнул хотя бы раз, его нужно бросить со скоростью больше 0, 5 м/с (2 км/ч), камень радиусом 2, 5 см и той же массой ― больше 1 м/с (4 км/ч). [А. Зайцева. «Блинчики» на воде по-научному // «Наука и жизнь», 2006]
>
> Снизим цену ― и заберем часть рынка у конкурентов. **Пример**. В 2005 году устоявшаяся цена на пленку для припрессовки (для изготовления книжных обложек) европейского производства, составляла 0, 115-0, 120 долларов/м. [В. Зюзько. Маркетинг: работа над ошибками // Coach, 2008]
>
> Это очень важный метод. **Пример**. Из памяти часто «выскакивают» имена и фамилии, которые вы раньше легко вспоминали. [К. Уманский. Что-то с памятью моей стало... // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]
>
> Если же цель ― создать скандал вокруг объявления, но при этом сохранить «солидный» имидж товара, эта очень тонкая работа требует профессионального подхода. **Пример**. Перед страховым брокером стояла двойная задача: продвинуть и себя, и новую категорию при сравнительно малых бюджетах. [Владимир Ляпоров. Маркетинг: как это делается (2004) // «Бизнес-журнал», 2004.01.30]

Но мне симпатичней предложения из двух слов: **"Приведу пример", "Вот пример", "Такой пример", "Другой пример"** и т. п.

Comment: В ваших выдержках как раз-таки в качестве примера приводится одно предложение, если, конечно, в цитате указан весь пример.