# Двоеточие перед целым абзацем

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие, оформление-текста, абзац

Допустимо ли ставить двоеточие в конце абзаца, который вводит изложение по какой-то теме или пример, который содержится в следующем абзаце? Если да, укажите ссылку на правило.

*Для начала развеем мифы:*

*[Абзац из развёрнутым изложением мифов]*

---

*Рассмотрим пример:*

*[Абзац из изложением примера]*

---

**Дополнение**

*Серьёзность компании придают не красивые слова, а сильные факты. Если у компании есть достижения, то о них можно рассказать и без пафоса:*

*Мы проектируем спутники для ABC. Создаём надёжные и безопасные ракеты, экологичные системы выведения на орбиту. Иногда в процессе открываем новые материалы, которые становятся...*

---

*Вот некий копирайтер сочинил текст о сервисном центре:*

*ABC — динамично развивающаяся компания. Мы абсолютные лидеры рынка ремонта мобильной техники. В нашей команде работают настоящие профессионалы, которые подходят к своей работе с максимальной отдачей. Наши клиенты получают...*

Comment: Подобный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439719/%d0%a2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80

Answer (score 1):

Нужно ставить точку.

> 9.Точка ставится в конце предложения, вводящего в дальнейшее развернутое изложение: Вот этот рассказ. (Пауст.) [дальше следует рассказ]; Представьте себе следующее, [дальше — подробное повествование]; Новый станок имеет такое устройство. [дальше — пространное описание]. ([§ 1. Точка](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=87#_ftnref10))

Подобный вопрос Вы уже задавали: [Точка или двоеточие после слова “пример”?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439719/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80)

Comment: Вопрос немного другого содержания. Здесь предложения находятся в разных абзацах. Добавил ещё пару конкретных примеров. Кстати, у Розенталя опечатка? После "Представьте себе следующее" стоит запятая, а не точка.

Answer (score 0):

Да, если это заголовок. Для более точного ответа нужен не схематичный образец.

Comment: Что значит — «если это заголовок»? Заголовок можно завершить двоеточием?

Comment: https://texterra.ru/blog/kakie-znaki-prepinaniya-stavit-v-kontse-zagolovka.html

Comment: «Двоеточие в конце заголовка лишнее и легко убирается без потери смысла.» И это — то самое, на чём ответ основан? Не слабо.

Comment: Ага. А в своей сути всё это ссылается на правила русского языка, в котором ряд терминов определён с помощью определяемых терминов. Чтобы вы понимали, это что-то на подобии синий это голубой, а голубой это синий. И поверьте, это ещё не самое страшная тайна русского языка.

Comment: Вроде в конце заголовка не ставится никакого знака, кроме многоточия, восклицательного и вопросительного знаков.